# Performance considerations regarding Date Vs. Char/Number/Varchar2 in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, datatypes, performance-tuning, query-performance

I've been working with Oracle 11g for about 7 years and I was asked for a consulting job on a small project.
The problem they had was high CPU usage (more than 90%) on a 11gR2 with Windows2008 as platform. They had this server crashing once in a while, so they increased the resources but they still have high CPU usage. From my understanding, high CPU usage itself does not imply an issue, but when I drilled down a bit, it got more interesting:

There was a query which had a significant amount of elapsed time per each execution. As they used Oracle Standard edition, I was unable to use the benefits of AWR but, as I checked the query, I saw something very strange.

The query is as follows, which uses function foo:

```
update LIST_JOURNAL
   set STATUS       = '4',
       END_DATE     = :b1,
       END_TIME     = :b2,
       END_TYPE     = '1',
       USER_ID  = 'SYSTEM',
       ELAPSED_TIME = FOO_FUNCTION(START_DATE, START_TIME, :b1, :b2)
 where (((TERM_ID = :b5 and NODE_CD = :b6) and GROUP_CD = :b7) and
       STATUS < '4');
```

They used only `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2` and `NUMBER` as their datatypes (don't know the reason, maybe due to some migration from another database) and there is this `FOO_FUNCTION` in this query that calculates the interval between two timestamps, say one of them is a record in database and one of them is sysdate, (date and time are stored with `CHAR` and `NUMBER` datatypes, not `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`) the function converts sysdate to string using `TO_CHAR`, then concatenate with TIME field, then do a `TO_DATE`, then subtract and then multiply to seconds in a day (60*60*24) and return the results. (For contract reasons, I cannot disclose the function code)

The function looks very strange to me and I want to flag it as a very important CPU bottleneck my report for database performance boost. I haven't seen the rest of the functions but I'm pretty sure wherever `DATE` is needed, something similar happens.

But I'm a bit reluctant to do so, as I've not seen any evidence in Oracle docs or somewhere else that this might be a problem. (I know, the function is so oddly written that my reluctance looks ridiculous) Also there is a good chance that software vendor does not accept this as a change.

My questions are :

1. Is the above function can be a CPU intense one? Can refactoring and using `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types help boost the performance? Why? I can deduct some reasons, but as I need to present this, if there are some documents that have discussed the issue, I would be most grateful to see the links.
2. The table itself does not have any indexes - except for primary key - If we are stuck with the current code and situation, can an index help boosting the performance? How effective and sustainable can that be? I know I cannot expect detailed answers, but the table contains about 3.7M rows and I think for an update query, some indexes can help.

And my general questions:

3. Is there a performance downside for using `CHAR` and `NUMBER` instead of `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP`?
4. What would you recommend to my client?

**Update:**

I finally got the results. We added the following composite index :

```
create index I_LIST_JOURNAL ON LIST_JOURNAL (TERM_ID, NODE_CD, STATUS);
```

We instantly got some good results, CPU got down to 80 percent and execution time of a couple of queries decreased substantially (The query in question had average execution time of 15 million seconds, now it's about 2400 seconds average) but again, after a couple of days, it went up to 99 percent again..
I am looking to do another iteration of stat gathering and explain plan. But I'm not sure whether this helps reducing the load or not. I am thinking of adding a couple of other composite or simple indexes on the tables which have long running queries to eliminate "Table access full" in explain plan, but given the situation above and the tools I have, is there any other method I can use to get better results?

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: do you have installed STATSPACK? If I remember right you can use it to get an overview about the resource consumption of your queries.

Comment: As far as I know, STATSPACK comes with Enterprise edition, My client has Standard Edition installed.

Answer (score 2):

You want to flag the function for the reason of CPU bottleneck, based on what?

You could say you found the `sql_id`, and checked `v$sql`, compared `elapsed_time` to `plsql_exec_time` and found that a huge portion of `elapsed_time` comes from `plsql_exec_time` and `cpu_time` is also high.

Verify this with:

`select elapsed_time, plsql_exec_time, cpu_time from v$sql where sql_id = '...';`

Or even better, you can check where the time is actually spent with:

`alter session set statistics_level=all`;

Run the statement:

```
update LIST_JOURNAL
   set STATUS       = '4',
       END_DATE     = :b1,
       END_TIME     = :b2,
       END_TYPE     = '1',
       USER_ID  = 'SYSTEM',
       ELAPSED_TIME = FOO_FUNCTION(START_DATE, START_TIME, :b1, :b2)
 where (((TERM_ID = :b5 and NODE_CD = :b6) and GROUP_CD = :b7) and
       STATUS < '4');
```

Then view the actual statistics of this execution with:

`select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));`

The above gives you exact execution count, timing, cardinality, buffer gets, disk reads, temp, memory, etc. information about each step of SQL execution. This works in any edition of the database and does not require any licensed option. There are various ways of achieving the above

There is no index on the `LIST_JOURNAL` table, but it has 3.7 million rows and the above output indicates that your statement performed a `TABLE ACCESS FULL` on `LIST_JOURNAL` with 100000 buffer gets but 0 reads because the table is in cache, but this step actually returned only 5 rows (A-Rows) and this step took 10 seconds, while the whole execution took 10.2 seconds? Sure, you are very likely to have a missing index problem. What index to create? We do not know, because the distribution of the data is unknown to us. You may need a composite index with all columns in the predicates or just 3 of them or a simple index on only the `TERM_ID` column may suffice.

Or the time spent in most steps is insignificant, but the time spent in the UPDATE step is high, combined with `plsql_exec_time` being relatively high compared to `elapsed_time` and a relatively low amount of affected rows? Sure, check the function.

The above is the absolute minimum that I would check, before even thinking about the datatypes used in the function. Collect the facts first before theorizing without the slightest idea where the problem originates from.

Some answers to the original questions:

1. Yes, it can be. Even with the proper datatypes.
2. Yes, it can. Depends on the data distribution, number of affected rows.
3. Depends. Typically yes, when storing dates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out (without embarrassing me!) that it is good to not assume anything and do some more digging.  Nice idea to set `alter session set statistics_level=all` and do the `format=>'allstats last'` trick; just don't forget to reset the `statistics_level` back to original level!

Answer (score 1):

If the table used correct datatypes for date fields, the need for `foo_function` disappears; you can just subtract two date datatypes from each other and it yields the number of days and fractional portion of a day difference.  Oracle stores date data types internally as numbers, and so you can do simple date arithmetic, and it has a plethora of built-in optimized functions for doing more advanced date manipulation.  As your example is written, Oracle has to do a context switch between SQL and the function's PL/SQL engine; perhaps for each row.  There is your bottleneck, combined with extra code to convert `CHAR` and `NUMBER` datatypes around inside `FOO_FUNCTION`.

If you cannot alter the schema, but can use virtual column definitions (depending on your version of Oracle and your vendor's software) you could create a virtual column `START_DATE_TIME` of the correct `DATE` datatype and then no need to call `FOO_FUNCTION`.

And if all you can do is add an index, just

```
create index I_LIST_JOURNAL ON LIST_JOURNAL 
  (TERM_ID, NODE_CD, GROUP_CD, STATUS);
```

The order of the columns should probably be different based on cardinality, etc. of each column.  The `STATUS` column should be last as it is a range check, not equality check.  And if `STATUS` is just a small number of values, say 20 or less, you would actually omit that from the above index and also create a bit-mapped index on just the `STATUS` column, if there is not a lot of concurrent access to the table during these updates. (A bit-mapped index will briefly lock the table during any update.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will mark this as "answered" soon, when I get the results from the client. For "status" column, it has a cardinality of 9, but the table has about 5000 DMLs running each day, which are mostly INSERT and UPDATE. Do you think bit map can help for this column? I think b-tree will help a lot but not sure about bitmap indexes. @Mark Stewart

Comment: If there is a lot of querying of the table that could be occurring during the DML, you would run the risk of the bitmap index blocking the queries, so I would say no bitmap; especially with the number of DML statements/day.  If the data for the `STATUS` column is skewed, (IE 90% are closed status, etc.), then include the column in the composite index, or at least ensure statistics are being gathered on that column: